# Allow a mock class to inherit from a final class

Tags: c++, unit-testing, c++11, c++14

We may declare a final/sealed non-inheritable class using the new C++ keyword `final`.

```
class Generator final
{

};
```

This class may inherit from other, may or may not have virtual (inherited or not). But, how to make it `final`, yet allow one class to inherit from it?

We mostly need to derive a mock class from real class (with or without late-binding, hence `virtual` isn't important). How to make it work:

```
class MockGenerator : Generator{};
```

But disallow any other inheritance?

Comment: I dont think you can. Once class/struct is final, thats it, game over inheritance-wise

Comment: I agree - I don't think that in C++11 you can override 'final' keyword. If it's final - it is final. However, maybe you can consider other method of making class non-inheritable (depends on how you want to use it): http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/final-classes.html

Comment: another question: why do you want to mock a final class? Shouldn't you mock an interface, in case your [architecture is ok](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But, how to make it final, yet allow one class to inherit from it?

That's not possible.

> We mostly need to derive a mock class from real class (with or without late-binding, hence virtual isn't important).

If the class is final, you *do not need to derive from it*. If you *do* need to derive from it, *it is not final*. Pick one.

**Edit**: You *can* add restrictions to your class, but those come at their own cost to the interface:

```
class Generator // not final
{
    Generator(); // the only accessible constructor is private

    // whitelist who has access to this constructor
    friend class MockGenerator;
public:
    // no public constructors here except for copy & move

    Generator(Generator&);
    Generator(Generator&&);
    ...

    // provide controlled access to the private constructor
    static Generator make_generator() { return Generator(); }

    // rest of API here
};
```

This is a class that allows it's factory and MockGenerator specializations to call it's constructor. This comes at the price of blocking trivial construction though.

Old code (no longer compilable):

```
Generator instance;
```

New code (enforced by the private constructor):

```
auto instance = Generator::make_generator();
```

Answer (score 5):

One possibility: use a define for final and define it as empty when generating the test environment.

```
#ifdef MOCK
#define CLASS_FINAL
#else
#define CLASS_FINAL final
#endif
```

---

**edit:** I agree with the comment of utnapistim: this is not a recommendation, just a technical possibility (but at least better than `#define final`).

Comment: Please do not recommend this. It is a solution that tests code different than production code (and - by definition - not what you end up shipping). If written code is not testable, that's a design problem and it should be solved at design level, not at "hack the meaning of keywords" level (I saw a similar solution on SO, proposing `#define private public` as a workaround for untestable code).

Comment: Note that there can be differences in what code the compiler produces based on `final` -- a pointer to a `final` method or class can devirtualize all calls through it.  This can, for example, possibly causing inlining that did not occur before.  Inlining where the function looks different in different TUs can expose UB.  Methods defined in body of a class are implicitly inline.  Plus performance changes.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to create mock class it for unit-testing, then you can try [Typemock Isolator++](https://www.typemock.com/isolatorpp-product-page). Because it easily handles with `final` classes. You don't even need to change something in you production code (like creation of separate mock class). I've created simple test to demonstrate it:

```
class Generator final
    {
        public:
            int foo()
            {
                return 0;
            }
    };

    TEST_METHOD(TestFinal)
    {
        Generator* generator = FAKE<Generator>();
        WHEN_CALLED(generator->foo()).Return(1);

        int result = generator->foo();

        Assert::AreEqual(1, result);
    }
```

Hope it can be useful for you.