# Is it possible to mock private/protected methods from a c++ class without inheriting from it?

Tags: c++, c++11, googlemock

I am trying to use gMock framework to mock a method functionality for one of my classes. But the class is declared final. As per working through examples in https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/pwnall/googletest/+/HEAD/googlemock/docs/for_dummies.md#how-to-define-it and https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/google/googletest/+/refs/tags/release-1.8.0/googlemock/docs/CookBook.md#mocking-private-or-protected-methods I have this understanding that the mocking interface must inherit from the actual class containing the function to be mocked. In my case though, the actual class is declared final . Is there any workaround for this ?

Comment: Hints: [Allow a mock class to inherit from a final class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26465237/allow-a-mock-class-to-inherit-from-a-final-class)

Comment: Related: [Mock static method from external Class (that I can't change!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63630216/mock-static-method-from-external-class-that-i-cant-change). The answer shows (particularly for GTest) how to leverage static dependency injection to delegate test calls to a mocked class (that does not derive from the product class) during test.

Answer (score 0):

Make a separate class which contains an instance of the `final` class, and add a `friend` declaration to the `final` class to allow the new test class to access whatever you need.

Comment: That introduces test code dependency on the production code. Making a test class `friend` is a code-smell to me.

Comment: @Quarra: IMO it's less bad than templatizing everything as you suggest in your answer.

Comment: `final` shouldn't be used too often either way - it's a very strong contract. Using `friend` should be avoided as it introduces tight coupling. Templates on the other hand are widely used, e.g. almost whole STL is templatized and is widely considered as a great C++ library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [hi-perf dependency injection technique](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/google/googletest/+/refs/tags/release-1.8.0/googlemock/docs/CookBook.md#mocking-nonvirtual-methods). This way the class you're mocking can be `final` or can even have non-virtual methods.